# Replacing the Wordpress password validation

Tags: users, login, password, validation

I have a custom application with thousands of users who already have a password stored.  I would like to set up a self hosted wordpress site to accompany that application and to use the usernames and encrypted passwords that already exist in that database.

Is there a way to configure Wordpress to not use the normal list of users, but instead to validate usernames and passwords against another database on another server?

We have a team of developers so if there was a way to write code to hook into the login process this would be acceptable.  Does anyone have experience with this, or have any suggestions of where to look?

Comment: Really what I am looking for is a way to replace the user list with a call to a different database, on that exists already from a different system.  Any suggestions on where to start with this.

Comment: Interesting thread at [wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-December/044874.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Investigating the filter `authenticate`, we can find that it is called [inside](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L460) the function [`wp_authenticate`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate), which is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions).

That means that it can be replaced by one of our own making.

This is the **original function**, plus a marked entry point:

```
function wp_authenticate($username, $password) {
    $username = sanitize_user($username);
    $password = trim($password);

    $user = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);

    /* ENTRY POINT */

    if ( $user == null ) {
        // TODO what should the error message be? (Or would these even happen?)
        // Only needed if all authentication handlers fail to return anything.
        $user = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));
    }

    $ignore_codes = array('empty_username', 'empty_password');

    if (is_wp_error($user) && !in_array($user->get_error_code(), $ignore_codes) ) {
        do_action('wp_login_failed', $username);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

---

The **test was done** creating a `wp_authenticate` function inside a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). On that entry point, I put the following:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_users';
$parent = $wpdb->get_row( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name='$username'"
    )
);
if( $username == $parent->name && $password == $parent->password )
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $parent->id );
```

---

The table `wp_my_users` is a simple test table, password is even plain text.
[image: demo user table]

---

**The matter** is how build the `$user` object completely based on a custom table. Or if it is feasible or advisable...

Because in this test the ID of the users is the same, so we are giving back ([`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)) to WordPress a user from its own table `wp_users`, but with credentials checked in a custom table `wp_my_users`.

---

**Notes**:

This answer doesn't goes beyond the analysis and hacking of the function `wp_authenticate`. No consideration is done about security, password management nor the `wp_usermeta` table.

For reference, this is the content of `$user`:

```
user  |  WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_login] => rod
            [user_pass] => $P$BQ8qnb3iYPRzisxYHUKq5X/GCQqhoz1
            [user_nicename] => rod
            [user_email] => name@email.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2012-09-21 14:39:01
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => rod
        )

    [ID] => 1
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [administrator] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => administrator
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [switch_themes] => 1
            [edit_themes] => 1
            [activate_plugins] => 1
            [edit_plugins] => 1
            [edit_users] => 1
            [edit_files] => 1
            [manage_options] => 1
            [moderate_comments] => 1
            [manage_categories] => 1
            [manage_links] => 1
            [upload_files] => 1
            [import] => 1
            [unfiltered_html] => 1
            [edit_posts] => 1
            [edit_others_posts] => 1
            [edit_published_posts] => 1
            [publish_posts] => 1
            [edit_pages] => 1
            [read] => 1
            [level_10] => 1
            [level_9] => 1
            [level_8] => 1
            [level_7] => 1
            [level_6] => 1
            [level_5] => 1
            [level_4] => 1
            [level_3] => 1
            [level_2] => 1
            [level_1] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
            [edit_others_pages] => 1
            [edit_published_pages] => 1
            [publish_pages] => 1
            [delete_pages] => 1
            [delete_others_pages] => 1
            [delete_published_pages] => 1
            [delete_posts] => 1
            [delete_others_posts] => 1
            [delete_published_posts] => 1
            [delete_private_posts] => 1
            [edit_private_posts] => 1
            [read_private_posts] => 1
            [delete_private_pages] => 1
            [edit_private_pages] => 1
            [read_private_pages] => 1
            [delete_users] => 1
            [create_users] => 1
            [unfiltered_upload] => 1
            [edit_dashboard] => 1
            [update_plugins] => 1
            [delete_plugins] => 1
            [install_plugins] => 1
            [update_themes] => 1
            [install_themes] => 1
            [update_core] => 1
            [list_users] => 1
            [remove_users] => 1
            [add_users] => 1
            [promote_users] => 1
            [edit_theme_options] => 1
            [delete_themes] => 1
            [export] => 1
            [administrator] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
)
```

Comment: great details.  Thanks for the help.  you get the bounty.

Comment: @SteveStedman : Thanks, hope it can give a head start. Researching for the function and filter names in this Stack surely will provide handy info. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can bypass login mechanism of wordpress by login user automatically (after they succesfuly passed with credentials from another website for example) with this function: wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);

for example with this you do login admin (user with id = 1)

```
wp_set_auth_cookie(1); //after this admin is logged in
```

so you can create user in wordpress with specified user privileges and then as user log with another credentials you can log him as this "placeholder" user.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'my_auth', 10, 3 );

function my_auth( $user, $username, $password ){
    // your validation here.
    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin [External Database Authentication](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/) fits your needs. From there you might enable already logged-in users setting the cookie when they login just using `wp_set_auth_cookie` as @Roman says.