# wordpress get gallery images title

Tags: images, gallery, get-the-title

I am retrieving some images post with:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
```

How can I retrieve the image title?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress attachments are stored as posts so you can use most of the post specific WordPress calls and functions to read/write data associated with the attachment. This applies to post meta data for an attachment as well.

So in this case, since you have the post ID ( same as $attachment_id ) you can simply use the `get_the_title()` function:

```
$sImageTitle = get_the_title( $attachment_id );
```

This returns a string of the post's title for the given post ID.

See more info. at the codex docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

Comment: Stephen, at least link the function name to the Codex. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656

Comment: Thanks, I typically do but missed it this time. I've edited my answer to add the link.

Comment: Check toscho's comment [to this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73280/12615). I'm writing this comment on the Low Quality queue...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Still learning the ends and outs here.

Comment: Updated to provide more information and hopefully more helpful.